# Microsoft Access - The field 'column bound' doesn't work properly

Tags: ms-access

I have problem with the 'column bound' option.

I want to create a combo box so that the field will show an other table field, and when I open the box it will show the first 3 columns. When I choose the row, I want it to save the 2nd value.

For that I defined the field like this:

1. Display control - combo box
2. Row source data - Table/Query
3. Row source - Customers
4. Bound column - 2 ; column count - 3

When I click and chose a row from the list that roll down, it shows me the first column value in the cell, instead of the second column value.

Can someone help me figure out the problem? (I check the field type and its fine - text)

Thanks in advance,
Gal :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the widths of the preceding columns to 0 if you don't want them visible. Otherwise when you bind the columns they show exactly as they are formatted in the table. i.e. if you want to display column 3, columns 1 and 2 need to be set in the display to Column Widths..... 0";0";1". You should notice when you expand the field that all three columns are displaying, but you only see the data from column 1 because the rest is being cut off in your box.

Comment: Hi and tnx for the help, but probably i wasnt clear enough. When i clicked on the box, i want to see 3 coloums,and it work. The problem is when i chose one of the options from the list, i expect to see the coloum 2 value fill the cell (because i chose 'bound colomn'=2), but i get the first coloum value instead. Any suggestions?

Comment: As a temporary solution if the order of your parent table doesn't matter you can go into the design view of the table and move column 2 to be column 1.

Comment: Ohh. Great idea! Still i realy want to know if i dont forgeting something, or missing some important info.

Comment: The Access help file states that only the first visible column will be displayed in the results of a drop down field, so the only real solution is to either re-organize your table, or build a Query off your table with duplicate info before and after the display columns with the first column set to .01" so it's not visible but still displays that value in the Dropdown.

Comment: So what the roll of the 'bound colomn', the help state that this is her job - to specify what colonm to show in the end, or am i wrong?

Comment: From the help file: The leftmost visible column in a combo box (the leftmost column whose setting in the combo box's ColumnWidths property is not 0) contains the data that appears in the text box part of the combo box in Form view or in a report. The BoundColumn property determines which column's value in the text box or combo box list will be stored when you make a selection. This allows you to display different data than you store as the value of the control.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is set the dropdown as two values only, one hidden with the actual bound value and the other with whatever you want to display. For example if the 3 columns you wanted displayed are: [ID], [Name] and [Address] and you want [Name] to be your "bound" field your rowsource should be:

```
SELECT [Name], [ID] & ' - ' & [Name] & '-' & [Address] As DisplayField FROM Customers
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by 'mkinson' above; your table's field-level property 'Column Width' has to be set to 0" for ones which you would not want to show up inside your combo box.
Example: If you have three columns, but you want to show only the column 2; In the table design view->Field properties->Column Width has to be set with a value 0";1";0".
Similarly, if you want to show only the column 3; you would set the Field-level Column Width property to 0";0";1".

Answer (score 0):

This can be confusing since the column order that is displayed in the dropdown list is NOT zero-based. In other words, the first column, whether it is displayed or not, is 1, not 0.

So, if you are selecting Col_ID; col_Name and col_Address for the list and you want to store col_ID but only display col_Name and col_Address, you would specify a Column Count of 3 with display widths of 0";1";2" but SET THE BOUND COLUMN AS 1, NOT 0.

However, in VBA, if you want to refer to the value in that hidden first column, the one we just called Column 1, it is referred to as column 0. Like cmb_Customer.Column(0).